# How to iterate through an in-memory zip file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip, in-memory, rack-test

I am writing a unit test, and one of them is returning a zip file and I want to check the content of this zip file, grab some values from it, and pass the values to the next tests.

I'm using Rack Test, so I know the content of my zip file is inside `last_response.body`. I have looked through the documentation of [RubyZip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) but it seems that it's always expecting a file.  Since I'm running a unit test, I prefer to have everything done in the memory as not to pollute any folder with test zip files, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> See [@bronson’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475895/214790) for a more up to date version of this answer using the newer RubyZip API.

The Rubyzip docs you linked to look a bit old. The [latest release (0.9.9) can handle `IO` objects](https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/blob/0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_input_stream.rb#L77), so you can use a StringIO (with a little tweaking).

Even though the api will accept an `IO`, it still seems to assumes it’s a file and tries to call `path` on it, so first monkey patch `StringIO` to add a `path` method (it doesn’t need to actually do anything):

```
require 'stringio'
class StringIO
  def path
  end
end
```

Then you can do something like:

```
require 'zip/zip'
Zip::ZipInputStream.open_buffer(StringIO.new(last_response.body)) do |io|
  while (entry = io.get_next_entry)
    # deal with your zip contents here, e.g.
    puts "Contents of #{entry.name}: '#{io.read}'"
  end
end
```

and everything will be done in memory.

Answer (score 20):

Matt's answer is exactly right.  Here it is updated to the new API:

```
Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(input)) do |io|
  while entry = io.get_next_entry
    if entry.name == 'doc.kml'
      parse_kml(io.read)
    else
      raise "unknown entry in kmz file: #{entry.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

And there's no need to monkeypatch StringIO anymore.  Progress!

Comment: what does input need to be?  File?  path?

Comment: A string of binary Data. That is the content of the zip file if read from file or if requested from url

Answer (score 8):

```
Zip::File.open_buffer(content) do |zip|
  zip.each do |entry|
    decompressed_data += entry.get_input_stream.read
  end
end
```

Comment: some explanation can go a long way to encourage understanding rather than copy-paste-move on

Answer (score 4):

With [RubyZip](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip/versions/1.2.1) version `1.2.1` (or maybe some previous versions too), we just need to use `open_buffer` method of `Zip::File` class.

From RubyZip documentation:

> Like #open, but reads zip archive contents from a String or open IO stream, and outputs data to a buffer. (This can be used to extract data from a downloaded zip archive without first saving it to disk.)

Example:

```
Zip::File.open_buffer(last_response.body) do |zip|
  zip.each do |entry|
    puts entry.name
    # Do whatever you want with the content files.
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this working for you? When I do this, I get the error detailed [here](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/177)

Comment: Works for me, recommend this

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Tempfile` to dump the zip file into a temporary file. Tempfile creates an operation-system specific temporary file which will be cleaned up by the OS after your program finishes.

Comment: On POSIX systems, the temporary file is already "deleted" when you get it, so there's no clean-up required. It's the closest thing you can get to a naked filehandle to a transient file object.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Matt's answer I have a slightly modified solution for those who have to use 0.9.x rubyzip gem. Mine doesn't require a new class definition.

```
sio = StringIO.new(response.body)
sio.define_singleton_method(:path) {} #needed to create fake method path TO satisfy the ancient rubyzip 0.9.8 gem
Zip::ZipInputStream::open_buffer(sio) { |io|
    while (entry = io.get_next_entry)
        puts "Contents of #{entry.name}"
     end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. In my case I have only one file so I used a fixed path, but you can use `entry.name` to build your path.

```
input = HTTParty.get(link).body
Zip::File.open_buffer(input) do |zip_file|
    zip_file.each do |entry|
      entry.extract(path)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this one due to changes at rubyzip:

```
Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(zip_file)) do |io|
  while (entry = io.get_next_entry)
    # deal with your zip contents here, e.g.
    puts "Contents of #{entry.name}: '#{io.read}'"
  end
end
```