# Ruby: Download zip file and extract

Tags: ruby, zip, rubyzip

I have a ruby script that downloads a remote ZIP file from a server using rubys `open`command. When I look into the downloaded content, it shows something like this:

```
PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\b\x00\b\x00\x9B\x84PG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x10\x00foobar.txtUX\f\x00\x86\v!V\x85\v!V\xF6\x01\x14\x00K\xCB\xCFOJ,RH\x03S\\\x00PK\a\b\xC1\xC0\x1F\xE8\f\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00PK\x01\x02\x15\x03\x14\x00\b\x00\b\x00\x9B\x84PG\xC1\xC0\x1F\xE8\f\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\xA4\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00foobar.txtUX\b\x00\x86\v!V\x85\v!VPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00D\x00\x00\x00T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

I tried using the Rubyzip gem (https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) along with its class `Zip::ZipInputStream` like this:

```
stream = open("http://localhost:3000/foobar.zip").read # this outputs the zip content from above
zip = Zip::ZipInputStream.new stream
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```
 Failure/Error: zip = Zip::ZipInputStream.new stream
 ArgumentError:
   string contains null byte
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible, in general, to download a ZIP file and extract its content in-memory?
2. Is Rubyzip the right library for it?
3. If so, how can I extract the content?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution myself and then at stackoverflow :D ([How to iterate through an in-memory zip file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730720/how-to-iterate-through-an-in-memory-zip-file-in-ruby))

```
input = HTTParty.get("http://example.com/somedata.zip").body
Zip::InputStream.open(StringIO.new(input)) do |io|
  while entry = io.get_next_entry
    puts entry.name
    parse_zip_content io.read
  end
end
```

1. Download your ZIP file, I'm using HTTParty for this (but you could also use ruby's `open` command (`require 'open-uri'`).
2. Convert it into a `StringIO` stream using `StringIO.new(input)`
3. Iterate over every entry inside the ZIP archive using `io.get_next_entry` (it returns an instance of `Entry`)
4. With `io.read` you get the content, and with `entry.name` you get the filename.

Comment: I tried this same code above but doesn't work for me, I see this error: `rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_input_stream.rb:52:in `initialize': can't convert StringIO into String (TypeError)`

Comment: I'm using `rubyzip` `1.1.7`, so maybe thats the problem? Have you copy & pasted my code from above? At which line (in your code) does the error happen?

Comment: yea, turns out that the remote zip I was accessing was corrupted. All good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Like I commented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43303222/4196440, we can just use `Zip::File.open_buffer`:

```
require 'open-uri'

content = open('http://localhost:3000/foobar.zip')

Zip::File.open_buffer(content) do |zip|
  zip.each do |entry|
    puts entry.name
    # Do whatever you want with the content files.
  end
end
```